# atmega328p UART rx pin

Tags: avr, uart, atmega328p

I have [simple co2 meter](https://github.com/bazhenov/co2-meter/tree/main/firmware) using atmega328p as uC (Arduino mini Pro board actually). Microcontroller is sending measurements over FT232RL to a PC host (one way communication from AVR to PC), but this part of schematics is irrelevant as you'll see later.

All works quite as expected when I left RX pin floating on AVR side (I'm not reading anything from UART): I can get representative data on the PC side. But when I connect AVR RX – FT232RL TX, I have no transmission over UART. Using logic analyzer I see there is even no start condition on AVR TX pin.

Using scope I figure out that after FT232RL is powered up there is some delay and then both DTR and TX pin of FT232RL show following:

[image]

*CH1 – 5V power rail powering both AVR/FTDI, CH2 – FT232RL DTR/TX pin (both have basically the same signal)*

AVR UART transmitter stops sending any data (there is no start condition on AVR TX pin) after first transition to HIGH at CH2.

At this point I disconnect FT232RL from AVR entirely and figure out that any signal transition from LOW to HIGH on AVR RX pin at any moment stops UART transmitter.

Next using logic analyzer and some "pin toggling debugging" I have confirm following:

- `UDRIE` flag is enabled, so `UDR` vector should be called (I'm using interrupt based UART);
- global interrupt flag is enabled and timer interrupts works as expected
- invocation of `UDRE` interrupt handler stoped right after aforementioned LOW->HIGH transition on AVR RX pin;
- `USART_RX` interrupt handler is never called under any circumstances.

Also I've found configuring `PDO` as GPIO instead of UART TX solves the problem, which is quite obvious at this point.

What can cause AVR UART transmitter to stop working in such circumstances and what tests can I perform to locate problem further?

Comment: did you configure the pin data direction etc? try running the example code from the datasheet....